Non-Ramsey function $f:[\omega]^{<\omega}\to\{0,1\}$
Let $\newcommand{\o}{\omega}\o$ be the set of non-negative integers, and for any set $X$, let $\newcommand{\oo}{[\o]^{<\o}}X^{<\o}$ denote the collection of all finite subsets of $X$.
What is an example of a function $f:\oo\to\{0,1\}$ with the following property?

Whenever $X\subseteq \o$ is infinite, then the restriction $f|_{X^{<\o}}:X^{<\o}\to \{0,1\}$ is non-constant.


A boring example would be the function that sends the empty set to zero and all other sets to one.

For $P \subset \omega$ finite, let $f(P) = \#P \bmod{2}$, i.e., $f(P) = 0$ if $P$ has even cardinal, and $1$ otherwise.

Or $f(P)=g(#P)$ where $g:\omega\to{0,1}$ is any nonconstant function. Or $f(P)=1$ if $#P=\min P$ and $f(P)=0$ otherwise.

@bof Yes, there are tons of examples.
